# Meteor + React + CollectionFS + GridFs + DropZone: importing server side

Tags: reactjs, meteor, gridfs, collectionfs, react-dropzone

All seems go well until i include the Images Collections in server side. After that meteor doesn't start.

commons.js

```
export const Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("images", {path: "~/Descargas"})]
});
```

server.js

```
import '../imports/api/commons.js';
```

Comment: I don't think the `GridFS` store accepts a `path`

Comment: fs: collection is deprecated try using meteor files (https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) they have a section for react.